# Can GEKKO solve the problem that two dynamic optimal control processes are conducting simultaneously?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

[image: multiple-target optimal control problem]

I will be grateful for any tiny advice.
The code below is modified based on the code written by @TexasEngineer, but I still feel it's not exactly what I want.
P.S. There is an article that dealt with the almost same problem using a very complex programming method, I didn't fully understand their method due to my limited knowledge, although they explained the whole process of programming in great detail in their appendix.(See https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w27840/w27840.pdf)

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# define variables
t = np.linspace(0,100,101)
m = GEKKO(); m.time=t
tt = m.Var(0)
x = m.Var(50,lb=1e-5)
u = m.Array(m.MV,2,value=1,lb=1e-5,ub=10)
# differential equation
m.Equation(x.dt()==x*(1-x/2)-u[0])
m.Equation(tt.dt()==1)
# Change u1 to maximize the first objective function, and change u2 to maximize the second objective function, and let the two processes alternate.
if (-1)**tt.value-1==0:
    u[0].STATUS = 1
    u[1].STATUS = 0
else:
    u[0].STATUS = 0
    u[1].STATUS = 1
# create parameter to maximize only final integral
final = np.zeros(101); final[-1]=1
p = m.Param(final)
# objective 1
m.Maximize((((-1)**tt+1)/2)*p*m.integral((10-5/x)*np.prod(u)))
# objective 2
m.Maximize(-((((-1)**tt+1)/2)-1)*p*m.integral((20-8/(x*u[1]))*u[0]))
# solve
m.options.IMODE=6
m.options.NODES=3
m.options.MAX_ITER=200
m.solve()
# plot
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'k-',label='x')
plt.plot(m.time,u[0].value,'b--',label=r'$u_1$')
plt.plot(m.time,u[1].value,'r:',label=r'$u_2$')
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.ylabel('Value'); plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you make a first attempt at this? Here are similar benchmark problems to help guide you. You can just add the two objectives to the problem statement and Gekko creates the summation. https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MoreDynamicOptimizationBenchmarks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Gekko can solve multiple objectives but just add them together. There is one piece of information missing from your problem statement. It doesn't specify if `u(t)` is `u1(t)` or `u2(t)` in the differential equation. Here is a version that assumes it is `u1(t)`. A lower bound of `1e-5` is included for `x` and `u` to avoid divide by zero.

[image: Solution]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0,10,101)
m = GEKKO(); m.time=t
x = m.Var(50,lb=1e-5)
u = m.Array(m.MV,2,value=1,lb=1e-5,ub=10)
for i in range(2):
    u[i].STATUS=1
# create parameter to maximize only final integral
final = np.zeros(101); final[-1]=1
p = m.Param(final)
# objective 1
m.Maximize(p*m.integral((10-5/x)*np.prod(u)))
# objective 2
m.Maximize(p*m.integral((20-8/(x*u[1]))*u[0]))
# differential equation
m.Equation(x.dt()==x*(1-x/2)-u[0])

# solve
m.options.IMODE=6
m.options.NODES=3
m.solve()

# plot
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'k-',label='x')
plt.plot(m.time,u[0].value,'b--',label=r'$u_1$')
plt.plot(m.time,u[0].value,'r:',label=r'$u_2$')
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.ylabel('Value'); plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is the IPOPT solution.

```
EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
 
 The solution was found.
 
 The final value of the objective function is   -1007.50065504272     
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   0.827599999996892      sec
 Objective      :   -1007.50065504272     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

You can get the maximize version of the objective function of 1007.5 with

```py
print(-m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

Gekko converts a `Maximize` problem into a `Minimize` problem by multiplying by `-1`. The objective that is reported by the solver is for a minimization so you need to multiply by the `-1` to get the original objective.

Comment: One thing that this solution doesn't do is maximize the first objective only by changing `u1` or selectively maximize the second objective only by changing `u2`. You may need to split the problem into two problems to have that degree of separation or use the `TIER` option in Gekko to prioritize which one optimizes first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, the big challenge for me is how to maximize the first objective only by changing u1, and maximize the second objective only by changing u2. I only found the explanation on TIER option at https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuning_params.html#tier and haven't found a specific example showing how to use this option. Can you share a simple example using TIER option in Gekko? That will help a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try setting `u[0].TIER=1` and `u[1].TIER=2`. You'll see the optimizer run twice and only use `u[0]` the first time through and then `u[1]` the second time through. You may need to use an iterative approach where you successively set `u[0].STATUS` and `u[1].STATUS` to 0 (OFF) or 1 (ON) depending on which one you'd like to optimize. You can also control which objective is on or off by either multiplying that objective by 0 or 1 or setting up a `m.CV()` variable for the integrals and either setting the `TIER` or turning the `STATUS` on or off too.